# Why may we suppose $a=0$ in this proof?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I didn't understand why we may suppose $a=0$ in this proof:

[image]

I'm reading Conway's Complex Analysis book, page 31.

Any help is welcome

Comment: If $a \neq 0$, redefine $\tilde{z} = z - a$ and nothing changes in the proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just shifting: $z \to z-a$.

More clearly, you can think as $z-a=u$ and power series wrt $u$.

Comment: Yes, but why can I do this?

Comment: I added a bit more.